# Visual Studio 2010 throws exception on running unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

When I run the unit tests, Visual Studio throws following exception

> Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

Even it's not possible to run any of the tests, which means it's a setup issue with Visual Studio. Any workaround/solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Have you any logs from VS?
Otherwise have you tried to repair/reinstall VS?

Comment: Have you done a Hello World style unit test? This would verify that it has nothing to do with your unit tests.

Comment: @JérémieBertrand I created few tests in a new project and it works pretty well. It seems some problems with existing project.

Comment: The only solution left is to migrate all tests to a new test project and verify each test one by one...

Comment: Do your existing tests use Typemock?

Comment: It uses gmock @StephenOberauer

Comment: @sarat, did you find a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your UnitTest project has an invalid reference to another project (e.g. a project which has been deleted, or project type has changed from "library" to "utility").